# Detecting CTRL+C in Node.js

Tags: node.js, event-handling, copy-paste

I got this code from a different SO question, but node complained to use process.stdin.setRawMode instead of tty, so I changed it.

Before:

```
var tty = require("tty");

process.openStdin().on("keypress", function(chunk, key) {
  if(key && key.name === "c" && key.ctrl) {
    console.log("bye bye");
    process.exit();
  }
});

tty.setRawMode(true);
```

After:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on("keypress", function(chunk, key) {
  if(key && key.name === "c" && key.ctrl) {
    console.log("bye bye");
    process.exit();
  }
});
```

In any case, it's just creating a totally nonresponsive node process that does nothing, with the first complaining about `tty`, then throwing an error, and the second just doing nothing and disabling Node's native <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handler, so it doesn't even quit node when I press it.  How can I successfully handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in *Windows*?

Answer (score 274):

If you're trying to catch the interrupt signal `SIGINT`, you don't need to read from the keyboard. The `process` object of `nodejs` exposes an interrupt event:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log("Caught interrupt signal");

    if (i_should_exit)
        process.exit();
});
```

**Edit**: doesn't work on Windows without a workaround. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021373/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-process-onsigint-in-node-js)

Comment: For future readers, this question is answered for windows here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14861513/2020425

Comment: The windows problem is already fixed

Answer (score 28):

The NPM module, `death`, uses `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, and `SIGTERM`.

So basically, all you need to do is:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', () => {});  // CTRL+C
process.on('SIGQUIT', () => {}); // Keyboard quit
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {}); // `kill` command
```

As a side note, this may actually call `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, and `SIGTERM` numerous times... not sure why, it did for me.

I fixed it by doing this:

```js
let callAmount = 0;
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    if(callAmount < 1) {
        send.success(`✅ The server has been stopped`, 'Shutdown information', 'This shutdown was initiated by CTRL+C.');
        setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 1000);
    }

    callAmount++;
});
```

If all you want to do is detect the interruption keys, just use `SIGINT`

Edit: I didn't realize this post was very old, oh well, it's helpful to others I guess!

Comment: Very helpful answer thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For those who need the functionality, I found [death (npm nodule, hah!)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/death).

Author also *claims* it works on windows:

> It's only been tested on POSIX compatible systems. Here's a nice discussion on Windows signals, apparently, this has been fixed/mapped.

I can confirm <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works on win32 (yes, I am surprised).

Answer (score -3):

```
process.on('signal', async (signal) => {
    console.log('signal: ', signal);
    if (signal === 'SIGINT') {
        console.log('Received SIGINT. Calling save function...');
        await amazon.saveData();
    }

    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -8):

```
if (event.key == "ctrl+c") {
    console.log("goodbye");
    break;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `event.key` isn't for key combinations, so it will never be anything like `ctrl+c`.

Comment: `break` only works in `for` and `while` loops. Running it in an `if` statement will cause Node.js to crash. Use `process.exit()` instead.