# Is there a way to know if user ended process running inside integrated terminal via Ctrl+C?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm currently launching integrated terminal from my extension and sending it commands to run certain programs. I want to know if there's a way to know if user ended process from terminal via Ctrl+C instead of letting the process end on it's own?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting CTRL+C in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165605/detecting-ctrlc-in-node-js)

Comment: Sorry, these links doesn't answer my question