# Cannot detect exit event in node js

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a node js express app hosted on Azure (Microsoft server). For some reason, I get a feeling that the app restarts once in a while, and I want to catch and log this event. So I try this but it doesn't work:

```
process.on('exit', function (code) {
    var exitMsg = 'Process exited with code ' + code;

    // log exitMsg synchronously
});
```

I understand that on Windows there is some problem catching the exit event. Maybe you have some solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On azure/win this might help:

```
if (process.platform === "win32") {
  require("readline")
    .createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    })
    .on("SIGINT", function () {
      process.emit("SIGINT");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the `'SIGINT'` event. It occurs when your app is interrupted or cancelled.

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Process Interrupted, exiting');

  // eventually exit
  process.exit(); // Add code if necessary
});
```

Its worth noting though, if you're hosting your App in IIS using IISNode, this probably won't work.

Comment: Yes there is, `SIGINT from the terminal is supported on all platforms, and can usually be generated with CTRL+C (though this may be configurable). It is not generated when terminal raw mode is enabled.`

Comment: @jfriend00 just tested in `cmd.exe` and `powershell`, validated it works in both environments on Windows 7

Comment: OK, I guess it was added since [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021373/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-process-onsigint-in-node-js/14861513#14861513).