# python error Suppressing signal 18 to win32

Tags: python, winapi, signals, stdin

I created a simple test.py with the following:

```
import sys
res = sys.stdin.read()
print(res)
```

but when I tried to run

```
python test.py
```

then i input

```
hello
```

and end the input by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, I got the following message:

```
4 [sig] bash 11516! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 10620)
```

I could not figure out what was wrong.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

Signal 18 is just the handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. (Technically it maps to `SIGTSTP`.) The signal tells the process to suspend. Since the signal is generally meaningless to a Windows process, git-bash suppresses the message, but it still lets you know that it suppressed that signal.

Unfortunately, MinTTY, the default git-bash terminal, doesn't connect up the console correctly for native Windows console applications. So even ignoring the warning message, the python interpreter isn't really working correctly anyway. [*(More info)*](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ#some-native-console-programs-dont-work-when-run-from-git-bash-how-to-fix-it)

In order to get python hooked up correctly you need to use `winpty` to launch python. The command:

```
winpty python test.py
```

will work. You could also use git-cmd if you need access to git commands, or open a standard Windows command prompt and run python there if you don't.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun for the correction, I updated the answer. I'm not very well versed on the intricacies of POSIX signals, so if my explanation of the error message isn't very good, let me know and I can try again.

Comment: My comment was partly to note that this POSIX signals and pty emulation is functional for programs that use MSYS2. For example, if you run `cat` from this mintty bash session, you can (fake) suspend it with Ctrl+Z, return to bash and resume it with `fg`, and then end reading from stdin with Ctrl+D. It's just not applicable and generally broken when running WinAPI console applications. But your answer is fine, and I already upvoted.

Comment: If your terminal is stuck at the `[sig] bash 11516! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process`, just type something into the terminal like "hello" then press enter. Any Ctrl- command doesn't work. This is what I actually came to this question for.

Answer (score -2):

You can kill it from the Windows taskmgr.exe

Comment: Is there any dangling process after terminating with Task Manager?