# NodeJS process.kill doesn't seem to work on windows when I try to programatically send the SIGTERM signal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was just trying to work with signals like **SIGTERM** and **SIGINT**. The idea is I want to send **SIGTERM** signal with **process.kill(process.pid, "SIGTERM")** when something happens and then handle that signal with **process.on("SIGTERM", callback)**.

My expectation is that when **process.kill(process.pid, "SIGTERM")** runs, the SIGTERM handler should run the callback function and do some cleanup work.

But this does not happen and process exits without running the callback function.

```
if (condition) {
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM');  
}

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('SIGTERM SIGNAL RECEIVED');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Windows equivalent of process.on('SIGINT') in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021373/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-process-onsigint-in-node-js)

Comment: What OS? It's probably a Windows issue. I tried on Windows and I too didn't get the SIGTERM log, but weirdly I tried it on [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (Linux on Windows) on which it worked expected. Wouldn't be surprizing to me as Node.JS on Windows has a lot of such oddities. You may find more info on Node Github issues, such as this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12378

Comment: @vallentin that question is talking about **SIGINT** signal which is triggered when we hit CTRL + C from the terminal. I am asking about the "SIGTERM" signal and also i want to to trigger these signal from within my code. Not from terminal.

Comment: @laggingreflex yes i tried these signals on linux and they work perfectly fine. But not on windows.

Comment: @MubashirHassan Yes, I know. But the question contains related info. If I had to give an answer, I'd say "Signals is a POSIX thing, so don't expect them to work on Windows".

Comment: @vallentin yes i noticed it. it doesn't work on windows.