# Closing a Node.js server gracefully

Tags: node.js, http, webserver, sigint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graceful shutdown of a node.JS HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263716/graceful-shutdown-of-a-node-js-http-server)

I have a basic server in Node.js using the `http` module. While I know a `SIGINT` event will close the program and stop the server, it seems cleaner to use `server.close([callback])` to close the server (I'm doing this on `SIGINT` event, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299331/what-is-the-best-practice-to-gracefully-shutdown-a-node-js-program-from-an-exter)). This works nicely as long as the server has not received any requests. As soon as the server gets a request, even if my response is as simple as:

```
res.writeHead(500, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
res.end();
```

The callback from `server.close()` never gets called, and closer inspection reveals that `server.connections` is 1, not 0. (If I have it serve an HTML page with three external scripts, for example, `server.connections` will be 4.)

Why aren't these connections being terminated by `res.end()`? What can I do to gracefully stop my server? Or is this just overkill for an imagined problem?

Comment: Ah. I had looked at that question but misinterpreted what it was saying. Yes, I believe this is a duplicate.